# List keeps changing even if it is not called

Tags: python, string, list, function, while-loop

The list "stop" should contain the x and y coordinates given by function when the length of the string "stringa" is equal to the first x value given to the list (in this case 1023). The list(s) should not be changed more than once, this is made thanks to the list bool_stop that tracks the changes made to the list(s), in this way before chaging x and y values of the list one more time (in the while loop inside the function "failapiega") the if statemet will check if the list was alredy changed and blocks the action if so. That's why i don't understand why the list keeps changing values. I suppose there's something wrong outside the while loop in the function, but I cannot detect what.

```
x = 1
iterations = 10
stringa = "AB"
tot = 2 ** (iterations + 2)
In = tot / 4
stop = [[1, -1], [In - 1, None], [2 * In - 1, None], [3 * In - 1, None], [tot - 1, None]]
# stop[1] --> [1023.0, None] #
bool_stop = [True] * 4


def failapiega(stringa, stop, bool_stop):
    l = len(stringa)
    i = l - 1
    while i >= 0:
        p = stringa[i]
        if p == "A":
            stringa += "B"
            stop[0][0] += 1
        elif p == "B":
            stringa += "C"
            stop[0][1] += 1
        elif p == "C":
            stringa += "D"
            stop[0][0] -= 1
        elif p == "D":
            stringa += "A"
            stop[0][1] -= 1
        if bool_stop[0]:
            if stop[1][0] == len(stringa) - 1:
                bool_stop[0] = False
                stop[1] = stop[0]
        i -= 1
    return stringa, stop, bool_stop


while 0 <= iterations:
    stringa, stop, bool_stop = failapiega(stringa, stop, bool_stop)
    iterations -= 1
```

Debugging I found out that

```
 if stop[1][0] == len(stringa) - 1:
                bool_stop[0] = False
                stop[1] = stop[0]
```

this part is only executed once, despite that stop[1] keeps changing every time.

Comment: Because you have done this: 

`stop[1] = stop[0]`

stop[0] and stop[1] refer to the same object. If you change the values in one, the other will change. 

Could be linked.

Comment: Thanks really a lot. I spent 2 days trying to deal with this.

Comment: No problem. I'll convert it to an answer; I'd love an upvote and accept.

Comment: Btw,  `bool_stop = [True] * 4` looks a bit odd given that you only use bool_stop[0]

Comment: I acces the other indexes of `bool_stop` later in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing `stop[1] = stop[0]` stop[0] and stop[1] refer to the same object. If you change the values in one, the other will change.

You can do the following instead to create a separate object,
`stop[1] = list(stop[0])`

Be aware of this when working with anything that isn't a primitive 
https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Python_Concepts/Basic_data_types#Primitive_Variables